# É possível converter ao mesmo tempo várias tabelas de MyISAM para InnoDB?

Tags: mysql

Preciso converter várias tabelas criadas com engine MyISAM para engine InnoDB.

São cerca de 250 tabelas e gostaria de saber se é possível converter todas elas de uma vez pela linha de comando do mysql ou pelo phpmyadmin. Converter eu sei que é possível, mas fazer isso uma de cada vez seria muito trabalhoso. Alguém sabe se é possível? E se for, como isso poderia ser feito?

Answer (score 1):

É possível com uma única linha bash:

```
for t in `mysql MEU_BD -Bse 'show tables;'`; do mysql MEU_BD -e "alter table $t engine=InnoDB;"; done
```

Answer (score 0):

Pode tentar assim (1 tabela por linha, não esquecendo do **;**)

```
ALTER TABLE t1 ENGINE = InnoDB;
ALTER TABLE t2 ENGINE = InnoDB;
ALTER TABLE t3 ENGINE = InnoDB;
[..]
```

Answer (score 0):

Escrevi a stored procedure abaixo que faz o que você precisa, recomendo testar **BEM**  ela antes em ambiente de desenvolvimento ou homologação! Não me responsabilizo por eventuais problemas =)

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `convert_tables`(IN schema_name VARCHAR(255))
BEGIN
DECLARE n INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE i INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE t VARCHAR(255);
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema = schema_name AND engine = 'MyISAM' INTO n;
SET i=0;
WHILE i < n DO 
       SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema = schema_name AND engine = 'MyISAM' LIMIT i,1 INTO t;

        SET @alter_sql = concat('alter table ',t,' ENGINE = InnoDB;');

        PREPARE stmt FROM @alter_sql;

        EXECUTE stmt;
        DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

        SET i = i + 1;
END WHILE;
END
```

Para executar a stored procedure:

```
CALL convert_tables('teste');
```

Onde 'teste' é o nome do schema onde estão as suas tabelas.

Explicação:

A procedure inicialmente calcula a quantidade de tabelas com engine = 'MyISAM' e atribui esse valor à variável n.

Depois iteramos em cada linha da busca acima extraindo o nome da tabela para a variável t.

Tendo o nome da tabela em t, basta executar a comando `ALTER TABLE t ENGINE = InnoDB`, porém, não é possível executar diretamente o comando acima pois o MySQL não permite utilizar variáveis como placeholdes para as tabelas. Como workaround, precisamos construir a o comando acima em uma uma string e criar um statement a partir dele, depois disso basta executá-lo.

Fontes:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2754423/use-a-variable-for-table-name-in-mysql-sproc

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5817395/how-can-i-loop-through-all-rows-of-a-table-mysql